# Загрузилась ли страница на ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Пытаюсь написать модальное окно на React Js, чтоб оно появлялось сразу после загрузки страницы. Проверка как в нативном JS через    window.onload = funciton() {} не работает.

Помимо этого хотел бы поинтересоваться на счет правильности моего хода мыслей: создаю компонент ModalWindow(например).js , там пишу разметку и в render() {} пишу JS код. Затем стилизую и запускаю уже в компоненте основной страницы?

```
import React from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Modal.css';
import Link from '../Link';

class Modal extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    model: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };


  render() {
    window.onload = function () {
      document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn').onClick = function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName('modalWindow').style.display = 'none';

      };
    };

    return (
      <div className={s.modalWindow}>
        <div className={s.modal}>

          <h1>Modal window</h1>
          <p>fdsifjiodsjfiodsjiofjdsiojfioejwfiowejio jioewfjfiojewifwe jiowfj</p>

          <button className = {s.closeBtn}></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}


export default withStyles(s)(Modal);
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода!

Comment: @IhorTkachuk отредактировал запись

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы показать компонент после загрузки страницы, вам нужно использовать [методы жизненного цикла](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), а также внутреннее состояние компонента. Для доступа к DOM элементам компонента нужно использовать [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Самый простой вариант как-то так. В конструкторе определим начальное состояние окна:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        open: false,
    }
}
```

Далее методы для управления состоянием:

```
hide() {
    this.setState({
        open: false,
    });
}

show() {
    this.setState({
        open: true,
    });
}
```

После того, как компонент отрендерился, в методе `componentDidMount()` показываем окно:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.show();
}
```

и немного поправим метод `render()`

```
return (
  <div className={this.state.open ? 'show': 'hide'}>
    <div className={s.modal}>

      <h1>Modal window</h1>
      <p>fdsifjiodsjfiodsjiofjdsiojfioejwfiowejio jioewfjfiojewifwe jiowfj</p>

      <button onClick={() => this.hide()} className = {s.closeBtn}></button>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: благодарю Вас за понятный и полный ответ, но при нажатии на кнопку окно остается и не закрываетя...

Comment: скорее всего дело в стилях, неправильно стилизовал и вот. 
еще раз благодарю, надеюсь на подсказку в случае каких-то мелких вопросов.